# Puzzle that defies the brute force approach?

Tags: python, math, puzzle

I bought a blank DVD to record my favorite TV show. It came with 20 digit stickers. 2 of each of '0'-'9'.
I thought it would be a good idea to numerically label my new DVD collection. I taped the '1' sticker on my first recorded DVD and put the 19 leftover stickers in a drawer.
The next day I bought another blank DVD (receiving 20 new stickers with it) and after recording the show I labeled it '2'.
And then I started wondering: when will the stickers run out and I will no longer be able to label a DVD?
A few lines of Python, no?

**Can you provide code that solves this problem with a reasonable run-time?**

**Edit**: The brute force will simply take *too long* to run. Please improve **your algorithm** so your code will return the right answer in, say, a minute?

Extra credit: What if the DVDs came with 3 stickers of each digit?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: so you always get +20 stickers with each blank dvd?

Comment: Assuming you want to number sequentially, you will be able to number up to 10 DVDs with 2 or 3 stickers per digit (spd), 11 with 4 spd, 20 with 12 stickers per digit, 30 with 13, and so on. Main reason being you'll run out of 1s quite early.

Comment: @Franci: Not if you get another set of stickers with *every blank DVD*...

Comment: @knittl and @Franci - yes, you get 2 stickers with EVERY blank DVD.  
@Oded - Nope. not homework. A fun puzzle I ran across 15 years ago...

Comment: @Jon Skeet - that assumes the OP continues to buy blank DVDs for the stickers. The smart move would be to just buy additional stickers, or better yet - get el cheap perm-marker.

Comment: Real programmers tape their first DVD a '0' sticker.

Comment: From 15 years ago, did you know the answer? Getting 20 digits per DVD intuitively puts the shortage rather far away... @Franci, yes it should be a CW... else it's subjective and argumentative...

Comment: Besides, the puzzle does not really "defies the brute force approach"...

Comment: Thank you for improving the wording: it is understandable now.

Comment: OK, seeing the first answers, I understand better the "defies the brute" mention.

Comment: @Tal: Please provide further details and/or a solution to work towards. We need to be able to test our answers.

Comment: I would guess that thinking about, and brute-forcing, the problem *in a lower base* might be a good way to gain some insight into an *mathematical*, rather than purely computational, solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completely new solution. 6 bajillion times faster than first one.

```
time { python clean.py ; }
0: 0
1: 199990
2: 1999919999999980
3: 19999199999999919999999970
4: 199991999999999199999999919999999960
5: 1999919999999991999999999199999999919999999950
6: 19999199999999919999999991999999999199999999919999999940
7: 199991999999999199999999919999999991999999999199999999919999999930
8: 1999919999999991999999999199999999919999999991999999999199999999919999999920
9: 19999199999999919999999991999999999199999999919999999991999999999199999999919999999918

real    0m0.777s
user    0m0.772s
sys 0m0.004s
```

code:

```
cache = {}
def how_many_used(n):
    if n in cache:
        return cache[n]
    result = 0
    if int(n) >= 10:
        if n[0] == '1':
            result += int(n[1:]) + 1
        result += how_many_used(str(int(n[1:])))
        result += how_many_used(str(int(str(int(n[0])-1) + "9"*(len(n) - 1))))
    else:
        result += 1 if n >= '1' else 0
    if n.endswith("9" * (len(n)-0)) or n.endswith("0" * (len(n)-1)):
        cache[n] = result
    return result

def how_many_have(i, stickers):
    return int(i) * stickers

def end_state(i, stickers):
    if i == '':
        return 0
    return how_many_have(i, stickers) - how_many_used(i)

cache2 = {}
def lowest_state(i, stickers):
    if stickers <= 0:
        return end_state(i, stickers)
    if i in ('', '0'):
        return 0
    if (i, stickers) in cache2:
        return cache2[(i, stickers)]

    lowest_candidats = []

    tail9 = '9' * (len(i)-1)
    if i[0] == '1':
        tail = str(int('0'+i[1:]))
        lowest_candidats.append(end_state(str(10**(len(i) - 1)), stickers))
        lowest_candidats.append(lowest_state(tail, stickers - 1) + end_state(str(10**(len(i) - 1)), stickers))
    else:
        tail = str(int(i[0])-1) + tail9
        series = end_state(tail9, stickers)
        if series < 0:
             lowest_candidats.append(lowest_state(str(int('0'+i[1:])), stickers) + end_state(i[0] + '0'*(len(i)-1), stickers))
        lowest_candidats.append(lowest_state(tail, stickers))
    result =  min(lowest_candidats)
    cache2[(i, stickers)] = result
    return result

def solve(stickers):
    i=1
    while lowest_state(str(i), stickers) >= 0:
        i *= 2

    top = i
    bottom = 0
    center = 0

    while top - bottom > 1:
        center = (top + bottom) / 2
        if lowest_state(str(center), stickers) >= 0:
            bottom = center
        else:
            top = center

    if lowest_state(str(top), stickers) >= 0:
        return top
    else:
        return bottom

import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(sys.getrecursionlimit() * 10)

for i in xrange(10):
    print "%d: %d" % (i, solve(i))
```

Comment: Can you please add a few words about the algorithm? What does "lowest_state" do? I'm also pretty sure there is a way to calculate how_many_used directly, without recursion, but the code is already blazing fast as it is...

Comment: lowest_state returns what was lowest supply of '1' stickers when we buy `i` DVDs with `stickers` stickers in each.
In fact this number is always 0 or negative (because starting supply is 0, so lowest supply can't be higher)

Answer (score 7):

**This is old solution**, completely new 6 bajillion times faster solution [is on the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324306/puzzle-that-defies-the-brute-force-approach/3328629#3328629).

Solution:

```
time { python solution.py; } 
0: 0
1: 199990
2: 1999919999999980
3: 19999199999999919999999970
4: 199991999999999199999999919999999960
5: 1999919999999991999999999199999999919999999950
6: 19999199999999919999999991999999999199999999919999999940
7: 199991999999999199999999919999999991999999999199999999919999999930
8: 1999919999999991999999999199999999919999999991999999999199999999919999999920
9: 19999199999999919999999991999999999199999999919999999991999999999199999999919999999918

real    1m53.493s
user    1m53.183s
sys 0m0.036s
```

Code:

```
OPTIMIZE_1 = True # we assum that '1' will run out first (It's easy to prove anyway)

if OPTIMIZE_1:
    NUMBERS = [1]
else:
    NUMBERS = range(10)

def how_many_have(dight, n, stickers):
    return stickers * n

cache = {}
def how_many_used(dight, n):
    if (dight, n) in cache:
        return cache[(dight,n)]
    result = 0
    if dight == "0":
        if OPTIMIZE_1:
            return 0
        else:
            assert(False)
            #TODO
    else:
        if int(n) >= 10:
            if n[0] == dight:
                result += int(n[1:]) + 1
            result += how_many_used(dight, str(int(n[1:])))
            result += how_many_used(dight, str(int(str(int(n[0])-1) + "9"*(len(n) - 1))))
        else:
            result += 1 if n >= dight else 0
    if n.endswith("9" * (len(n)-4)): # '4' constant was pick out based on preformence tests
        cache[(dight, n)] = result
    return result

def best_jump(i, stickers_left):
    no_of_dights = len(str(i))
    return max(1, min(
        stickers_left / no_of_dights,
        10 ** no_of_dights - i - 1,
    ))

def solve(stickers):
    i = 0
    stickers_left = 0
    while stickers_left >= 0:
        i += best_jump(i, stickers_left)

        stickers_left = min(map(
            lambda x: how_many_have(x, i, stickers) - how_many_used(str(x), str(i)),
            NUMBERS
        ))
    return i - 1

for stickers in range(10):
    print '%d: %d' % (stickers, solve(stickers))
```

Prove that '1' will run out first:

```
def(number, position):
    """ when number[position] is const, this function is injection """
    if number[position] > "1":
        return (position, number[:position]+"1"+number[position+1:])
    else:
        return (position, str(int(number[:position])-1)+"1"+number[position+1:])
```

Comment: And a beautiful pattern emerges +1! Very cool! Playing with it now. Can someone please explain the resulting pattern?
Here is the logic, as I understand it: if you are at dvd # I (I being an N digit number), and you have S stickers in your leftovers stash, you can fast forward without checking the next S / N numbers (assuming there are that many N digit numbers left). This is the meaning of `min( stickers_left / no_of_dights, 10 ** (no_of_dights + 1) - i - 1)`

Comment: Less than 1 second to run on a very old desktop (for the requested 2 sticker version)! Less than 5 seconds to solve the 3 sticker version...

Comment: I'm happy to see that you are satisfied with this solution.

Comment: There was bug in solution. It should be:
    min( stickers_left / no_of_dights, 10 ** no_of_dights - i - 1)
I have fixed it (the results hasn't changed).

Comment: The resulting pattern emerges once you understand that 1 runs out first. If you prefer, the problem can be stated like this: For which number `n` does the sum of *1* digits in `[1-n]` become greater than `2*n`? @Tomasz: Absolutely awesome solution, by the way.

Comment: @Tomasz - 10X boost in your code when I realized that, at most a tenth of every digit is a 1, so the fast-forward should be: min( 10 * stickers_left / no_of_digits, 10 ** no_of_digits - i - 1). Can you update your code please?

Comment: It's not quite right. What about numbers like: 111111111123? When you fast-forward by small number, every move takes almost the same number of '1's.

Answer (score 6):

Here is **proof that a solution exists**:

Assuming you ever get to 21 digit numbers, you will start losing a sticker with every DVD you purchase and label (`(+20)  +  (-21)`).
It doesn't matter how many stickers you have accumulated until this point. From here on it is all downhill for your sticker stash and you  will eventually run out.

Comment: To those upvoting this post: This is by the OP himself. OP: Please put this information into your original post.

Comment: @silky: Answering your own question is useful and encouraged, since it adds to the community knowledge base.

Comment: @Daenyth: *sigh*. I wish I didn't have to explain this, but: 1) I don't disagree, 2) The op new this information at the time of posting the question.

Comment: @silky: I did know this info at the time of posting but felt it was part of the answer, sort of like a spoiler for the movie plot or a hint for a puzzle. It is not information needed to solve the question. I wouldn't have wanted other such posts to give hints as part of the question.... That said, if people disagree I will move it to the question.

Answer (score 2):

here's a quick and dirty python script:

```
#!/bin/env python

disc = 0
stickers = {
    0: 0, 1: 0,
    2: 0, 3: 0,
    4: 0, 5: 0,
    6: 0, 7: 0,
    8: 0, 9: 0 }

def buyDisc():
    global disc
    disc += 1
    for k in stickers.keys():
        stickers[k] += 1

def labelDisc():
    lbl = str(disc)
    for c in lbl:
        if(stickers[int(c)] <= 0): return False;
        stickers[int(c)] -= 1;
    return True

while True:
    buyDisc()
    if not labelDisc(): break

print("No stickers left after " + str(disc) + " discs.")
print("Remaining stickers: " + str(stickers))
```

i don't know if it yields the correct result though. if you find logical errors, please comment

result with debug output:

```
Bought disc 199991. Labels: 
Remaining stickers: {0: 111102, 1: 0, 2: 99992, 3: 99992, 4: 99992, 5: 99997, 6: 99992, 7: 99992, 8: 99992, 9: 100024}
```

Comment: MPAA will send their goons to your house before you buy even half that number. :-)

Comment: Seems to work correctly, but you are adding only 1 sticker of each 0-9 every round. Adding 2 would answer the original question, but not likely to stop any time soon...

Comment: @jari: adding +2 in every round lets the number of stickers grow and grow and grow. no end in sight (only after integer overflow :D)

Comment: @tal weiss: when you get 2 new stickers each per dvd, you will never come to an end. at least that's what bruteforcing shows. number of stickers climbing and climbing

Comment: @knittl well, bruteforcing is not proof. I've posted a proof of why the sticker pile will eventually run dry.

Answer (score 1):

The results for any base N and number of stickers per digit per DVD "S" are:

```
N\S ]      1 |        2 |          3 |         4 |    5 |        S?
===================================================================
  2 ]      2 |       14 |         62 |       254 | 1022 |   4^S - 2
----+--------+----------+------------+-----------+------+----------
  3 ]     12 |      363 |       9840 |    265719 |     (27^S - 3)/2
----+--------+----------+------------+-----------+-----------------
  4 ]     28 |     7672 |    1965558 | 503184885 |
----+--------+----------+------------+-----------+
  5 ]    181 |   571865 | 1787099985 |
----+--------+----------+------------+
  6 ]    426 | 19968756 |
----+--------+----------+
  7 ]   3930 | (≥ 2^31) |
----+--------+----------+
  8 ]   8184 |
----+--------+
  9 ] 102780 |
----+--------+
 10 ] 199990 |
----+--------+
```

I can't see any patterns.

---

Alternatively, if the sticker starts from 0 instead of 1,

```
N\S ]       1 |        2 |          3 |         4 |    5 |          S?
======================================================================
  2 ]       4 |       20 |         84 |       340 | 1364 | (4^S-1)*4/3
----+---------+----------+------------+-----------+------+------------
  3 ]      12 |      363 |       9840 |    265719 |       (27^S - 3)/2
----+---------+----------+------------+-----------+-------------------
  4 ]      84 |     7764 |    1965652 | 503184980 |
----+---------+----------+------------+-----------+
  5 ]     182 |   571875 | 1787100182 |
----+---------+----------+------------+
  6 ]    1728 | 19970496 |
----+---------+----------+
  7 ]    3931 | (≥ 2^31) |
----+---------+----------+
  8 ]   49152 |
----+---------+
  9 ]  102789 |
----+---------+
 10 ] 1600000 |
----+---------+
```

---

Let's **assume** that it's the “1” sticker running out first — which is indeed the case for most other computed info.

Suppose we are in base N and there will be S new stickers per digit per DVD.

At DVD #X, there will be totally X×S  “1” stickers, used or not.

The number of “1” stickers used is just the number of “1” in the digits from 1 to X in base N expansion.

Thus we just need to find the cross-over point of X×S and the total “1” digit count.

- N = 2: [1,2,4,5,7,9,12,13,15,17,20,22,25,28,32,33,35,37,40,42,45,48,52,54,57,…](http://www.research.att.com/~njas/sequences/A000788)
- N = 3: 1,1,2,4,5,5,6,6,7,9,10,12,15,17,18,20,21,21,22,22,23,25,26,26,27,…
- N = 10: [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,12,13,13,13,13,13,…](http://www.research.att.com/~njas/sequences/A094798)

there does not seem to be a closed for all these sequences, so a loop proportional X iterations is necessary.  The digits can be extracted in log X time, so in principle the algorithm can finish in O(X log X) time.

This is no better than the other algorithm but at least a lot computations can be removed. A sample C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static inline int ones_in_digit(int X, int N) {
    int res = 0;
    while (X) {
        if (X % N == 1)
            ++ res;
        X /= N;
    }
    return res;
}

int main() {
    int N, S, X;

    printf("Base N?   ");
    scanf("%d", &N);
    printf("Stickers? ");
    scanf("%d", &S);

    int count_of_1 = 0;
    X = 0;
    do {
        ++ X;
        count_of_1 += S - ones_in_digit(X, N);
        if (X % 10000000 == 0)
            printf("%d -> %d\n", X/10000000, count_of_1);
    } while (count_of_1 >= 0);
    printf("%d\n", X-1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 4^S and 27^S and …. maybe it's (S^S)^S?

Answer (score 1):

Here's some thoughts on the upper bound demonstrated by [@Tal Weiss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324306/puzzle-that-defies-the-brute-force-approach/3324796#3324796):

The first 21-digit number is `10^20,` at which point we will have *at most* `20 * 10^20` stickers. Each subsequent DVD will then cost us *at least* 1 net sticker, so we will definitely have run out by `10^20 + 20 * 10^20`, which equals `21 * 10^20`. This is therefore an upper bound on the solution. (Not a particularly tight upper bound by any means! But one that's easy to establish).

Generalising the above result to base `b`:

- each DVD comes with `2b` stickers
- the first DVD that costs us 1 net sticker is number `b ^ (2b)`, at which point we will have at most `2b . b ^ (2b)` stickers
- so we will definitely run out by `b ^ (2b) + 2b . [b ^ (2b)]`, which equals `(2b + 1)[b ^ (2b)]`

So for example if we work in base 3, this calculation gives an upper bound of 5103; in base 4, it is 589824. These are numbers it is going to be far easier to brute-force / mathematically solve with.